# How to fetch facebook comments into HTML?

Tags: facebook, comments

Facebook offers a [simple method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to add a Facebook comment function on your personal website or blog. But the CSS styles are Facebook's default style and cannot be modified.

There is [another method](http://www.infinitylist.com/2012/02/ueli-stecks-eiger-north-face-ascent/) to do this. Unlike the simple method above which uses `<iframe>` and ajax, this method seems to use PHP to fetch comments from Facebook and then put the comments directly into HTML so the related HTML codes and CSS styles can all be customized. Is there a tutorial that illustrate this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method doesn't use Facebook for commenting, it just uses Facebook accounts for authentication. The commenting system and comment data is stored outside of Facebook.

It's technically possible to do this using Graph API if you have a page with links for each story you want to comment on. Look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/ for information about retrieving and publishing to the comments for a link.

Comment: Thank you. So facebook accounts are used only for authentication, and all comments should be stored in my own database. I see. Since comments are not stored on facebook, may I skip the "Graph API" thing?

Comment: Yes, if you're storing and handling the comments yourself, you can ignore the Graph API thing.